# Lost wifi connection since i connected ethernet cable

Tags: wireless, network-manager, dhcp, wpa2

I've had trouble at my office using wifi. The thing is, the wifi network is totally seperate from the office LAN, and i've got to be on wifi if i want to use protocols like ssh or git.
I configured the wifi router to have a *permanent DHCP lease* on my Atheros card (using ath9k driver) and changed the password encryption to WPA2 (was using wep before... a shame). Also switched to channel 9, because the area is saturated with ch.11,6,7... emitters.

**All worked fine until i connected the ethernet cable again.** Now network manager (on Natty 11.04) spits this all over my syslog :

```
Oct  3 16:24:05 x wpa_supplicant[883]: Trying to associate with {box bssid} (SSID='xxxxx' freq=2452 MHz)
Oct  3 16:24:05 x NetworkManager[782]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
Oct  3 16:24:05 x kernel: [ 9792.310325] wlan0: authenticate with {box bssid} (try 1)
Oct  3 16:24:05 x kernel: [ 9792.319767] wlan0: authenticated
Oct  3 16:24:05 x kernel: [ 9792.319802] wlan0: associate with {box bssid} (try 1)
Oct  3 16:24:05 x wpa_supplicant[883]: Associated with {box bssid}
Oct  3 16:24:05 x NetworkManager[782]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> associated
Oct  3 16:24:05 x kernel: [ 9792.343240] wlan0: RX AssocResp from {box bssid} (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Oct  3 16:24:05 x kernel: [ 9792.343246] wlan0: associated
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.442339] wlan0: deauthenticated from {box bssid} (Reason: 2)
Oct  3 16:24:08 x wpa_supplicant[883]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid={box bssid} reason=0
Oct  3 16:24:08 x NetworkManager[782]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associated -> disconnected
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.507836] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.507843] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.507847] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512836] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain 
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512843] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512845] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512849] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512852] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512855] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512858] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct  3 16:24:08 x kernel: [ 9795.512860] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct  3 16:24:08 x NetworkManager[782]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
```

...and this goes on and on, trying to reconnect. Seems the authentification fails, but i don't understand why since it worked before i plugged the cable in. Any idea ?

**EDIT :** Supressed dhcp permanent lease, works again. Still interested about the cause ?!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a Terminal window:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo dhclient -r wlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "YOUR ESSID"
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. as i said, it works again since i've removed the DHCP permanent lease, and i see you use `dhclient -r` to force renewal of the lease. As stated, i'm curious of what could cause such behaviour ("locking" my connection because of a lease). Could you explain me why ?

Comment: dhclient -r actually removes DHCP. Then, we add it and we configure it.

Comment: accepted answer because it works, but i still don't understand why it won't work in the first place ... (ô_é)

Comment: Sure, I'll explain (I might have to divide it into a few comments).

Comment: The first command (ifconfig wlan0 down) disables the network interface, dhclient -r wlan0 removes the DHCP interfaces, and ifconfig wlan0 up enables the network again.

Comment: The iwconfig commands sets the ESSID and puts it into a managed mode (very important), and the last command configures DHCP.

Comment: You should really keep this command handy for whenever you have problems. I use it all of the time.

Comment: i don't mean to be a pain in the b.., but you're still explaining me **how** this fixes the problem, not **what is the problem**, its **nature and cause**. Thanks for your time, though.

Comment: De-accepted : happened again, and your solution does not work anymore. Help !

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about that. Your problem is that it doesn't connect the correct way. The commands make it connect the correct way.

Comment: Could you run the Network Information script (j.mp/Netinfo), and paste the generated file to pastebin or paste ubuntu (and of course, give me the link)?